# Trouble with Writing BMP file in C

Tags: c, hex, output, bmp

I am working on inputting a BMP and then manipulating the nearly every pixel in my 2D pixelarray and storing it in the array 2D pixelarrayout (which is seen inside of the first nested for loop in the final code segment below). I feel that the outputted BMP should be functional and everything seems to be alright when looking at the file through a Hex editor but for some reason the file cannot open properly. Any ideas why? Possibly an error in the header, but the first 54 bytes (size of both headers) of each file are the same

```
//make an instance of all output structure

    HEADER dataoutput;
    INFOHEADER data2output;
    char pixeloutput[pixelnum];

    int pixcount=0;
    for(r=0; r<rows; r++){
        for(c=0; c<collumns;c++){
            pixeloutput[pixcount]=pixelarrayout[r][c].Red;
            pixcount++;
        }
    }
    dataoutput.Type = data.Type;
    dataoutput.Size = data.Size;
    dataoutput.Reserved1 = data.Reserved1;
    dataoutput.Reserved2 = data.Reserved2;
    dataoutput.Offset = data.Offset;

    data2output.Size = data2.Size;
    data2output.Width = data2.Width;
    data2output.Height = data2.Height;
    data2output.Planes = data2.Planes;
    data2output.Bits = data2.Bits;
    data2output.Compression = data2.Compression;
    data2output.ImageSize = data2.ImageSize;
    data2output.xResolution = data2.xResolution;
    data2output.yResolution = data2.yResolution;
    data2output.Colors = 0;
    data2output.ImportantColors = 0;

    if( !(fileout = fopen( "CUoutput4.bmp","wb")))return  0;
    //calloc an array of 16 bytes set to NULL to be used to pad the end of the file 
    char *nullarray;
    nullarray = (char*) calloc(16,sizeof(char));

    fwrite(&dataoutput,sizeof(HEADER),1,fileout);
    fwrite(&data2output,sizeof(INFOHEADER),1,fileout);
    int i;
    char *pixelvaluehold;
    for(i=0;i<pixelnum;i++){
        pixelvaluehold = &pixeloutput[i];
        fwrite(pixelvaluehold,sizeof(char),1,fileout);
    }
    int count=0;
    while(( count + sizeof(HEADER) + sizeof(INFOHEADER) + pixelnum * sizeof(PIXEL) ) % 16 != 0){
        fwrite(nullarray,sizeof(char),1,fileout);
        count++;
    }

    fclose(file);
    fclose(fileout);

    free(pixelarray);   
    free(pixelarrayout);
```

And here are the structs for HEADER,INFOHEADER, and PIXEL

```
//define structures
    typedef struct 
    {   unsigned short int Type; /* Magic identifier */
        unsigned int Size; /* File size in bytes */
        unsigned short int Reserved1, Reserved2;
        unsigned int Offset; /* Offset to data (in B)*/
    }HEADER; /* -- 14 Bytes -- */

    typedef struct 
    {   unsigned int Size; /* Header size in bytes */
        unsigned int Width, Height; /* Width / Height of image */
        unsigned short int Planes; /* Number of colour planes */
        unsigned short int Bits; /* Bits per pixel */
        unsigned int Compression; /* Compression type */
        unsigned int ImageSize; /* Image size in bytes */
        int xResolution, yResolution;/* Pixels per meter */
        unsigned int Colors; /* Number of colors */
        unsigned int ImportantColors;/* Important colors */
    }INFOHEADER; /* -- 40 Bytes -- */

//restor original stack allignment  
#pragma pack(pop)

typedef struct
{ unsigned char Red, Blue, Green;
}PIXEL;
```

Comment: Try creating a similar bitmap file (same size, same colors, etc) in a paint program, then look at that in your hex editor alongside your code-generated .bmp file. Maybe there's an incorrect or missing header field, or maybe you've got byte-swapping or struct padding issues. Just a thought. Good luck.

Comment: The types in the BMP header file are 16-bit, 32-bit, etc.  Your types `unsigned` and `unsigned short` _might_ match, but may differ.  Suggest using fixed width types like `uint16_t`, etc.  Also insure your BMP typedefs are packed.

Comment: Have you printed the sizes of the structures (`printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(HEADER), sizeof(INFOHEADER));`?  Have you checked the sizes of the two files?  Since you're claiming the files are the same shape, the data segments should be identical in size too.  Is there a trailer section (I've not gone to look at the specification)?

Comment: I have checked, the files are the exact same size, 6064 bytes. both having the same 54 first bytes for the header, then another 6000 different bytes, followed by 10 matching NULL bytes to pad the end of the file. Very frustrating, but I would guess my header for the output BMP is unacceptable (the way it matches completely...not sure)?

Comment: What's the `width` of the image and how many `bits per pixel` are you using?

Comment: ".. followed by 10 matching NULL bytes to pad the end of the file" -- BMP files should not need padding to end-of-file. You don't say what `width` and `height` you are using, so it might be a [line padding problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042889/padding-a-bitmap-pixel-array).

Comment: Width is 300, height is 200, and bits per pixel is 24. I tried it without the padding before and it still did not work. Just ran with another compiler and I am getting a segfault somewhere in the code

Comment: sizeof(Header) + sizeof(InfoHeader) + width * height * bytes_per_pixel = 14 + 40 + 300 * 200 * 3 = 180054.

Comment: You are converting your image from 24 bits to 8 bits per pixel: `pixeloutput[pixcount]=pixelarrayout[r][c].Red;`. Are you adjusting your header correctly? If on purpose: an 8 bit BMP is automatically *indexed* color so it would need an additional palette. If not on purpose: copy the other RGB values as well.